How to send long strings by bluetooth HC05 module
I am building a bluetooth terminal app (Android) and want to send strings from my app to microcontroller via HC05 bluetooth module, I can share small strings near about 120 characters but while sending large strings of about 500 characters I am unable to receive by microcontroller or if even i get string i have random values.
I want to send 500 charcters via hc05 to microcontroller using bluetooth terminal app

Sounds like a resource problem. But you know, no MRE, no help. By the way, what is the HC05 connected to?

HC05 is connected with the mobile app, I have taken about reference from App link
